# newbie to javers , how to iterate and get all property names from a diff

Tags: javers

I am a newbie to javers.

I have two same objects with properties
I need to get a list of all the properties that are different.

this works

```
 Diff diff = javers.compare(memberFromDB, member);
 for (Change c : diff.getChanges()) {
        logger.info("change=" + c );
 }
```

and displays

> change=ValueChange{globalId:'com.stuff.Member/',
>   property:'currentRank', oldVal:'Friend12', newVal:'Dimaon'}

although i assume it is simple, how do i access the property of Change?

Or should i be iterating a different way thought the diff?

my end goal is to get a list of the properties that are different.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    diff.getChangesByType(PropertyChange.class).forEach(p ->
            logger.info("property change: "+ p.getPropertyName()  )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure this is the best way but it works

```
Diff diff = javers.compare(memberFromDB, member);
ArrayList<ValueChange> diffs = (ArrayList)diff.getChangesByType(ValueChange.class);

for (ValueChange v : diffs ) {
     logger.info("change=" + v.getPropertyName() );
}
```